# Mechanisms helping questions that didn't receive enough attention

Tags: feature-request, questions

**Phenomenon**

Users are intentionally choosing to read and answer easier and trivial questions. Nontrivial and meaningful questions do not receive enough attention.

In fact, most of the simple questions can be easily solved with Google. However, they occupied most of the places on SO.

Finding meaningful questions is becoming more and more difficult. Nontrivial and meaningful questions remain low views, no answers and no comments.

SO is becoming less interesting.

**Example for Illustration**

Trivial questions (even could be easily solved just with Google) gaining many immediate attention.

1. [ListView doen't work in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583246/listview-doent-work-in-fragment)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583387/could-not-open-file-with-its-default-program-from-html
3. [Android getting Error inserting to databse and code 19: constraint failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582156/android-getting-error-inserting-to-databse-and-code-19-constraint-failed)
4. [OnItemListener for Spinner without a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584508/onitemlistener-for-spinner-without-a-button)
   Nontrivial questions not receiving enough attention.
5. [Customizing a AlertDailog.Builder Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583435/customizing-a-alertdailog-builder-android)

Nontrivial questions not receiving enough attention.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584973/why-am-i-unable-to-upload-this-audio-file-to-parse
2. [GCM user notification - getting different notification_key when registering from device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584669/gcm-user-notification-getting-different-notification-key-when-registering-from)
3. [SearchView Voice Recognizer Does Not Transcribe Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584595/searchview-voice-recognizer-does-not-transcribe-text)
4. (Mine) [Styling attributes not functioning on merge tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584143/styling-attributes-not-functioning-on-merge-tags)
5. (Mine) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727161/carousel-consisting-of-bootstrap-3-responsive-blocks

Questions with not enough attention even with bounty started. Just marginally OK in the last few hours of bounty.

1. [PHP System Call Always Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368592/php-system-call-always-fails)
2. [RestKit addFetchRequestBlock causes objects not to be mapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355415/restkit-addfetchrequestblock-causes-objects-not-to-be-mapped)
3. [Google API Unable to Exchange Authorization Code for Access & Refresh Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388986/google-api-unable-to-exchange-authorization-code-for-access-refresh-token)
4. [ADB: Libraries to simulate bluetooth device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450290/adb-libraries-to-simulate-bluetooth-device)

**Existing Mechanism**

Bounty.

However, newbies and casual users do not have much reputation to spend. They just cannot afford such a luxury.

More mechanisms are needed as the situation is becoming worse.

**Possible Mechanisms Suggestion**

1. Add a *'cold'* category for recent questions not received enough attention. As a opposite to the *'hot'* category, *'cold'* questions deserve more attention.
2. Modify the ranking of *'interesting'* category. Questions not receiving enough attention deserve higher rank.
3. Bounty started by system. For example, low-viewed questions with no accepted answer asked before a week, *plus* 5 or more users flagged a new 'not received enough attention' flag. The exact criteria is debatable.

Comment: Could down-voters please at least explain? I spent time to identify the phenomenon and thinking of suggestions just aiming at making the site better. I don't think my suggestions just worth your speechless trampling.

Comment: This is meta. Downvotes just mean 'I disagree'. Questions like this get more favorable responses if they include links to actual examples, not just general claims.

Comment: 4 out of 5 questions you cited as not receiving enough attention were asked in the past 3 hours (isn't this too soon to state they did not get attention, especially considering we are on a weekend?).

Comment: @AndreSilva: And a long holiday weekend in the US to boot, when a lot of people are traveling or vacationing with their families.

Answer (score 9):

Can you prove your assertions? In my experience, the experts resemble a herd of hungry velociraptors, eager to leap on any answerable question. The questions that get ignored are not 'hard', they are poor questions for the site. At best they concern idiosyncratic circumstances. Can you cite examples of good, answerable, questions that languish for lack of predatory attention?

Comment: If you scan the *'interesting'* category on the front page, you could notice the phenomenon already. Trivial questions are gaining much more views immediately. Nontrivial questions are not even receiving enough views.
Example of trivial questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583246/listview-doent-work-in-fragment, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583387/could-not-open-file-with-its-default-program-from-html

Comment: Views are not an interesting metric.  Answers are what counts. Can you link to a single example question that has languished?

Comment: Example of nontrivial questions not receiving enough attention:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583973/chrome-packaged-app-with-a-java-applet, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583696/best-way-to-handle-communication-between-tablets-for-a-distributed-game, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583453/retrieving-regional-information-from-google-marketplace-downloads

Comment: @Gavin: Those aren't answerable.  It isn't clear what has been tried.  There's no code shown.  Can't troubleshoot an error without knowing what line is running when the error happens.

Comment: @Gavin: None of those 3 are good questions. I completely agree with bmargulies. I answer my share of easy questions, but that's mostly because I can't find enough interesting ones in my primary domains. If I see challenging and well asked questions in those domains, I'm normally all over it.

Answer (score 4):

The system already bumps older questions back onto the front page from time to time.  There's no bonus rep incentive like a bounty provides.

If you find a worthwhile question and don't have enough reputation to bounty it, mention it in a chatroom.  May get an answer immediately, or someone with enough rep may agree it is bounty-worthy.

Just don't overdo it.  You want to engage with the chatroom regulars, not come in and dump a list of questions and never be seen otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I would definitely try out asking for more help in chatroom.