# Tired of being completely ignored by SO community?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I have been a Stack Overflow user for quite a while and I would like to mention that my life as a programmer is incomplete without it.

With that said, I would really like to know why my questions are almost always ignored by the community despite the fact that they are completely legit, original and could potentially help a lot of people whereas questions which are relatively much much simpler, are often praised highly. 
Take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970663/ruby-extensions-from-c-stl) one for example and you can look at many others [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5668464/arafatk?tab=questions).

My questions are to the best of my knowledge very genuine and useful and it saddens me to see that questions that simply require a single search on Google and read the first documentation page that shows up are often the ones that are very popular.
Can you help me figure out what I could do? Should I post my questions little bit differently (like more or less explanation)? Should I not post questions complicated question at all, until I have much higher reputation?

Comment: Is it really surprising that more complex questions may take longer to be answered?

Comment: Referring to your initial example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549153/how-to-convert-protobuf-graph-to-binary-wire-format - this seems like a complex question that hasn't been as much *ignored* as it *hasn't been seen*. It was viewed 12 times when you posted this - that is very little. Not sure what to recommend except a bounty - if a Python veteran is willing to confirm it's a good and deserving question I'll be more than happing to put one on it

Comment: @Yannis I have changed the example. Please take a look.

Comment: "experts resemble a herd of hungry velociraptors, eager to leap on any answerable question. The questions that get ignored are not 'hard', they are poor questions for the site..." ([Mechanisms helping questions that didn't receive enough attention](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270247/839601))

Comment: @gnat This is not a duplicate. My questions are almost never downvoted, they are sometimes upvoted and sometimes they are left as it is.

Comment: I took a random sample of your questions and all were answered and accepted. I don't see your point.

Comment: duplicate is not about getting downvotes either, this was only a very minor point in the question there and neither of answers mentions it, all focus only on the ways to get more attention to the question

Comment: @gnat Thanks for the funny description. If you look at the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970663/ruby-extensions-from-c-stl You will find that this is a very reasonable question and could help hundreds of developers to speed up up there code. I now have the knowledge to make use of what I asked and I have greatly benefitted from it to the point that I made a very popular repository.

Comment: You received so many comments. When I did find an unanswered question, I found it to be too broad. Plenty of comments. Guess what? I have a higher unanswered ratio than you. IMHO, stop feeling so entitled. Nobody has to answer your question. And so many people tried to answer your question via comments.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC I have answered quite a few of them myself when no one took a try.

Comment: [This question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970663/ruby-extensions-from-c-stl) is just way too broad and/or lacks to ask a question (a bit like your initial revision on this meta question). It might benefit if you run your questions against the [checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @ArafatK copy what rene said. try going to SO documentation for the reputation, then you can start a bounty to attract more attention to your questions.

Comment: @ArafatK a lot of your questions are way too broad. look at the [mcve] guide and the [ask] guide. **Do your homework.**

Comment: Since I've gained so much rep recently, and I'm in a giving mood, show me one of the questions you want me to put a bounty on.

Comment: @ArafatK don't go down that route, please. That question has been on the site since 2009 when this site was different and since then it has been viewed 467866 times. Notice that is also has 27 down votes and was active 2 days ago. Your own question was viewed 38 times and last active 2 months ago. I hope you see that difference.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Thanks a lot. I have used the bounty idea myself for a very legitimate question. The question is about a gem that I own and it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448897/how-to-build-a-shared-library-for-tensorflow-on-travis-ci . I know that you can't put a bounty on this one because I already did but I got no answers.  If you really wish to help me then I would say this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549153/how-to-convert-protobuf-graph-to-binary-wire-format.

Comment: "tell if you really think that this deserves 1400 upvotes" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-can-i-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby has been viewed half a million times over seven years. Your questions are less than six months old. There is no basis for comparison there.

Comment: @ArafatK the system forces everybody to wait three days before setting a bounty to let the system process your question. I can't set a bounty now.

Comment: @ArafatK you realize your first question's bounty hasn't expired - bounties don't work instantly. they are a process. you need to wait and see

Comment: also, please please don't leave a space between your question mark. it's bad english. edit your answer

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC not to sound negative here. But I am sure that most likely this bounty will go to waste and I would have to figure it out myself.

Comment: @ArafatK it's been one day. you can't expect people to notice your question instantly. one out of seven days. you haven't placed a bounty yet, so you don't know.

Comment: "as a programmer", not "as a programmers"

Comment: @rene Sorry, I did not mean to do that.

Comment: @ArafatK I couldn't reward a bounty on your questions because I was out of town.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

At the begin, also I had a hard time. Looking to your questions, they seem not so bad.

Fight more, and answer more questions.

A little suggestion: you can draw *much* more attention if your question is easily understable already on the first spot. Consider, what the answerers see: 50 questions in a column, and it is up to them, where do they click. Correctly formulating the title is not a negligible thing, it is a critical one!

If you have at least a single golden badge, it has significant a psychological effect. Getting an elector badge is quite easy.

Yet another little tip: I've seen you don't like to end questions with a "?". Do it from now.

Comment: I don't agree with the *seem quitte high quality*. Based on what?

Comment: @rene I've checked his post history and found mainly interesting and HQ questions there, especially in the Ruby-C++ integration topic. He should invest more effort in the formalities, that's all.

Answer (score 11):

Things don't quite seem to be the way you describe them.  Out of your 22 questions, only 3 have *some* appearance of being ignored with no votes, no comments and no answers.  Out of those 3, one was posted this Sunday and the two other ones had elves that posted junk answers that were immediately deleted again.

Don't expect a flood of answers on a weekend. And surely those elves could have done a much better job by editing the question to re-activate it.

I don't really understand that kind of attitude.  But I suspect when SO gets to be the catch-all for things you don't want to have to do in your job then you'll have a lot more disappointment ahead.

Answer (score -3):

I understand that you feel ignored by the community.

There are only a few things I suggest.

As mentioned in the comments by @pekka-웃 you can put a bounty on your question...

To be honest the reason the simpler questions get praised highly, is because they are simply easier to understand.

To get people to answer longer more difficult question I think @pekka-웃 is right, give the community something in return.

Don't take lack of answers or votes as us ignoring you...

Hope you get your questions answered!

Answer (score -3):

- Search for answers on Stack Overflow and on Google. A lot of your unanswered questions could be answered with a Google search
- Use proper English.
- Let the system work. Wait a day or two before thinking your question is unnoticed.
- Try *asking very nicely* on Stack Overflow chat rooms.
- Read the How to Ask and creating a Minimal, Verifiable, Complete Example pages! This is very important.

And if none of those work...

- Set a bounty.

Don't have the rep? Well...

- Contribute to Stack Overflow Documentation